# yfinance (ticker).info not returning anything

Tags: python, yfinance

I've looked through multiple StackOverflow and GitHub posts, but none describe my issue.

```
import yfinance as yf
import time

msft = yf.Ticker("MSFT")
print(msft.info)
```

When I run this, it returns nothing. It doesn't exit me out of the console, it just 'stays still' after I press enter - I waited for about 15 minutes, but haven't received any output. I'm running OSX Catalina - I didn't install Python (3.8.5) with Homebrew. I already ran the `Install Certificates.command` file, so that isn't the issue. I'm stumped on this one. The code executes without me calling `msft.info`, so I know the issue is the info call. This may just be because my Mac is pretty slow - any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Have you tried calling any other methods?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Getting output for this and other tickers. MacOS 10.14, Python 3.7.3, yfinance 0.1.54. Also info is not a function that can be called, it is data dictionary,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**
I tried `pip install yfinance` in google collab and then

```
import yfinance as yf
import time

msft = yf.Ticker("MSFT")
print(msft.info)
```

it worked

Alternatively, you can use pandas_datareader.

```
    from pandas_datareader import data
    MSFT= data.DataReader("MSFT", start='2015-1-1', end='2015-12-31', data_source='yahoo')['Adj Close']

    MSFT
```

Comment: Pandas Datareader worked, but that isn't yfinance. Also, I'm using Sublime Text, not Colab. I'll just use DataReader, thanks!

Comment: @Landon `pandas_datareader` can work with `yfinance`. See [yfinance: pandas_datareader override](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance#pandas_datareader-override). Using this will download data faster. `yfinance` and `pandas_datareader` must both be installed, because they are not part of the standard distribution.

Comment: Ok - will do! Thank you!